# CNN for discrete regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have been trying to make a CNN model for my project for a while but i couldn't really make it work. My project is about designing a (40,40) filter with discrete values (0.125, 0.25, 0375, 0.5, 0.625, 0.75, 0875, 1.) using a two channel image like input (40,40,2) . I used scipy zscore on the inputs so they are between -2 to 2. My labels are (40,40) values (0.125, 0.25, 0375, 0.5, 0.625, 0.75, 0875, 1.).
 Untill now, i have been using regression to find values and round them to discrete values i want, but its becoming problematic and I'm having accuracy problems. The model i used :

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64,(5,5), input_shape = (40,40,2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64,(5,5)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(1600))
model.add(Reshape((40,40)))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

SGD = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0, decay=0.0, nesterov=False)

model.compile(loss='MSE',
             optimizer='SGD',
             metrics=['MAE'])

### Saving the model
checkpoint_path = 'training/cp.ckpt'
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

### Checkpoint callback
cp_callback = ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_path, 
                              monitor='val_loss',
                              save_best_only=True,
                              mode='auto',
                              save_weights_only=True,
                              verbose=1)

### Reduce LR on Plateau callback
lr_callback = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=2, verbose=0, mode='auto', min_delta=0.0001, cooldown=0, min_lr=0)

### Training the model
history = model.fit(intensity_train, doe_train,
          batch_size=16,
          epochs=15,
          validation_data=(intensity_val,doe_val),
          callbacks = [cp_callback, lr_callback])
```

And the graph is :
[loss and validation loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ks1k.png)

The problem is, when i check the results (I compare the rounded outputs with the original data with an algorithm) some datas have around 1590 correct and 10 incorrect values which is amazing. But for some, prediction is incorrect for all values. So i want my model to give outputs in the form (40,40) with the discrete values i gave earlier. Since the labels are in the same form, I think i can get better performance that way, but I'm not sure how to do that.

So my question is, how can i make it so the regression outputs are in the form i want.

Bonus question: How can i make a accuracy based metric such as 1560/1600 correct value ==> %97.5.

Comment: Here is an idea. Since you said that you have fixed discrete values as labels, and the o/p dimension is same as your i/p dimension, you can basically treat this as a segmentation problem. Where each of your discrete values, i.e. [0.125, 0.25, E.T.C] can be treated as a separate label and basically you are predicting the class for each of your [40, 40] pixels.

Comment: That is a great idea, however I don't really know how can i do that, i need to get a class output for all 1600 pixels, from 8 choice. How can i change my code to do that? Should i change my optimizer and loss function?

Comment: You can use some sort of encoder-decoder based architecture to do this. Here is an explanation of one of the most widely used segmentation n/w, U-Net. It starts from the very basic and gradually dives deeper. Hope this will help you in starting out. https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-semantic-segmentation-with-unet-6be4f42d4b47